# Didn't find class "java.lang.Math8" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, localdate

After migrating the Gradle version to 7.2, I get this error when running the application.
I noticed that it's pointing to Java 8 date/time feature, `LocalDate`.
My project already has `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true` enabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lots of searches without any result, I noticed only a simple solution as updating the coreLibraryDesugaring version will solve the problem. upgrading from `1.1.1` to `1.1.5`.
Hope this saves you some time!

Comment: Thank's @Amir, this definitely worked, I always wonder how people come up with solutions to these types of errors, I am not too familiar with Gradle so that may be it.
But nowhere in the error was specified nothing about desugaring, even though it was clear the jdk version "1.8" had something to do with the error, I'm still at lost how the desugaring interacts with android Gradle and the jdk...

Comment: Thanks, @Amir. Much appreciated answer :pray

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm that [Amir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71332084/2003580) solved this for me. Under dependencies, bump to this: `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'`

Comment: Glad this helped